# перегрузка бинарных операторов c#

Tags: c#

можно ли перегрузить бинарный оператор таким образом что бы передать в него больше двух параметров?
Т.е как то так

```
public static Point operator +(Vector Vx1, Vector Vy1, Vector Vx2, Vector Vy2,Point X, Point Y)
{
 return new Point (X+Vx1+Vx2,Y+Vy1+Vy2,0);
}
```

- это как пример того что я хочу сделать.
или кто может подсказать другой способ?

Comment: А как вы собираетесь такой небинарный оператор вызывать?

Comment: Ну из класса в котором я создаю перегрузку этого оператора.

Comment: Но как? Вот чисто синтаксически. Напишите, как должен выглядеть код вызова.

Comment: так я про код как раз и спрашиваю, тюк не знаю как это реализовать..?

Comment: Я спрашиваю не о том, как реализовать. Допустим, вы его как-то реализовали, как вы будете его **вызывать**? Для двух операндов `x` и `y` вы можете поместить `+` между ними: `x + y`. А между чем и чем вы поместите плюс для **трёх** (и более) операндов?

Comment: ну если я передаю шесть параметров 
Vector Vx1, Vector Vy1, Vector Vx2, Vector Vy2,Point X, Point Y
- можно разбить их на группы по три элемента и сложить их
(Vx1,Vy1,X)+(Vx2,Vy2,Y)

Comment: Операндов у Вас по прежнему два. Просто теперь это два кортежа.

Comment: Может и так ну у меня компилятор ругается на то что я в перегрузку бинарного оператора передаю больше двух операндов - а не в том как я вызываю это перегрузку перегрузку. Вот о чем я спрашиваю.
Пишет "Перегруженный бинарный оператор принимает два параметра"

Comment: @BadCats: Ну, эта проблема ясна. Но даже если вы сможете заткнуть сообщение об ошибке, всё равно вызывать вот так просто невозможно. А если вы будете складывать кортежи — для этого нужна функция сложения кортежей, которую написать невозможно, т. к. у вас нету доступа к исходному тексту кортежей (`ValueTuple`).

Comment: Нельзя. На то он и бинарный.

Comment: @VladD, `(+ v1 v2 v3 v4 ... )` :-D все уже придумано

Comment: @Grundy: C# такое не парсит, наши действия?

Comment: @VladD, сжечь C# :-D ну либо допилить компилятор, чтобы он уже парсил :)

Comment: @Grundy: Если мы будем сжигать каждый язык, который не понимает синтаксис всех других языков, то не останется вообще ни одного. Когда Хаскель научится понимать список аргументов в скобках, тогда и сожжём.

Comment: @VladD, чойта? lisp можно научить всему :-)

Comment: @Grundy Вот прям всему? Он сможет откомпилировать функцию `int f(int x, int y) => x + y;`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64175/discussion-between-grundy-and-vladd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автор, я не знаю, зачем тебе это нужно, но да, ты можешь сделать такое при помощи `ValueTuple`.

Ниже представлен код, который используется для поддержки описанного тобой решения, он не претендует на красоту и архитектурную грамотность.

**Конструктор и деконструктор вектора:**

```
public static implicit operator (int x, int y) (Vector v)
{
    return (v.X, v.Y);
}

public static implicit operator Vector((int x, int y) v)
{
    return new Vector(v.x, v.y);
}
```

**Конструктор и деконструктор поинта:**

```
public static implicit operator (int x, int y, int z) (Point v)
{
    return (v.X, v.Y, v.Z);
}

public static implicit operator Point((int x, int y, int z) v)
{
    return new Point(v.x, v.y, v.z);
}
```

**Оператор сложения поинта с кортежем:**

```
public static Point operator +(Point point1, (Point point2, Vector Vx1, Vector Vy1, Vector Vx2, Vector Vy2) t)
{
    return new Point(
        (point1.X + t.Vx1.X + t.Vx2.X),
        (t.point2.Y + t.Vy1.Y + t.Vy2.Y),
        0);
}
```

Применение:

```
Point point = new Point(1, 2, 3);

point += ((4, 5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10), (11, 12), (13, 14));
```

Смею заметить, что данное поведение АБСОЛЮТНО не очевидное, поэтому я настоятельно не рекомендую его использовать.

Как минимум, избавься от поинта `Y`, тогда подобное сложение будет хоть как-то понятно. Если ты это и имел в виду, то код будет более вменяемый:

```
public static Point operator +(Point point1, (Vector Vx1, Vector Vy1, Vector Vx2, Vector Vy2) t)
{
    return new Point(
        (point1.X + t.Vx1.X + t.Vx2.X),
        (point1.Y + t.Vy1.Y + t.Vy2.Y),
        0);
}
```